# node.js Expess https gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, express, https

**nodejs version v6.11.5**

When hosting via Express, the website loads, i.e,

```
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("The Server Has Started!");
});
```

But, when hosting via https, I get **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** error. For hosting with https, I'm using

```
var options = {
    ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/keys/sitname.ca-bundle'),
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/sitname.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/sitname.crt'),
};
var app = express();
.... the app .....
https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function(){
    console.log("server started at port "+port);
});
```

**The port is set to 80** and the ufw rules are as following

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Any response will be highly appreciable.

Comment: For https you have to set the port to 443 because https uses this port by default. Another option would that you define that you want to use port 80 for https when you send your request: https://my-domain.com:80. But I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: Thanks switching ports worked. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For https you have to set the port to 443 because https uses this port by default. Another option would that you define that you want to use port 80 for https when you send your request: my-domain.com:80. But I'm not sure if this works.

Answer (score 0):

From @floriangosse's comment,

HTTPS uses port 443 by default and thus using port 80 for HTTPS gives **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**.

**Switching to port 443 worked**.